# ROS Answers SE migration: ros_opentld

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a workspace and cloned ROS_openTLD from https://github.com/Ronan0912/ros_opentld,
and I run it in the following way,
`cd ros_opentld ; source devel/setup.sh ; roslaunch tld_tracker ros_tld_tracker.launch ; roslaunch tld_tracker ros_tld_gui.launch`.

but I don't know why there is always no image showing on the tld_gui window. I thought maybe I need to edit 'image_topic' in the launch file to the specific topic I used, but I don't know how to modify the  `<remap from="image" to="$(arg image_topic)"/>`. I'm not sure whether the modification is necessary. I am new to ROS and sorry I ask the silly question.
Someone else know the problem and can help?  Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213529/ros_opentld/) by [janis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23148/janis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Knowing the function of `arg image_topic`, I solved the problem by

```
roslaunch tld_tracker ros_tld_gui.launch image_topic:=/camera/image_raw
roslaunch tld_tracker ros_tld_tracker.launch image_topic:=/camera/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [janis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23148/janis/) with karma: 11 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0